# Node.js: Assign value to variable from html/js button

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, input

Is there an easy way in Node.js to do this without modules and stuff:

I need to create html/js buttons that onclick assign different values to a variable that is used in node.js for different things and without modules.

Comment: You mean you want the page running in someone's browser to assign values to a variable on the server?

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable. The click event should trigger an AJAX post to the server, containing the appropriate value. When the server gets that message and parses the JSON, get the value from the payload and set your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons need to be created using HTML/CSS. You could use Ajax to send information to the server. When a button is clicked, you could have an ajax call made to the server with the value of the button. When the server recieves that call, the server could assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also export server's functions using RPC(runs through websockets) and execute code of server right from browser. There are many libraries for that:
 https://zerorpc.dotcloud.com/, http://socket.io/

Answer (score 0):

It's just something running on localhost and with integrated html. Maybe you can see what I've tried below...

```
var ID;
var http = require('http');
 http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write('<html><head><script')
  res.write('function updateVar(){')
  res.write('ID = 12;')
  res.write('}')
  res.write('</script></head>')
  res.write('<body><input type="button" value="Show" onclick="updateVar()" />')
  if (ID == '12') {
  res.write('<svg><rect width="10" height="10" /></svg></body></html>');
  }
```